# How to solve a singularity problem for diferential equation?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods, boundary-value-problem, singularity-theory

Good day, Here is my equation

$$ (x-1)^2 (x-h)^2q_1(x,w)y''(x)+(x-1)(x-h)q_2(x,w)y'(x)+q_3(x,w)y(x)=0 $$ (with $q_1(x,w), q_2(x,w), q_3(x,w)$ regular functions). The boundary conditions are
$$ y(1)=0, \text{ and } y(h)=0 $$ 
 I need to find a numerical solution but unfortunately I am getting singularity problem in Maple  , is there any options to solve this issue?